# How a plist is used

Tags: iphone

What is the common use of plist? What kind of data we put in them? Is it always a dictionary kind of data we place in them? I believe we store them in either documents, temp or cache directory at run time, is it correct?

Comment: By the way, make sure you accept answers to your old questions.  Everything at stack overflow works off reputation points so be sure to thank people for answering your questions by selecting the check mark next to their answer.  You can view old questions in your profile here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/418029/abhinav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best source of information comes right from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope that helps!